# match string in JAVA

Tags: java, string, substring, match, string-comparison

I have a string written as **...YYK0***.

<.> (dot) - single occurrence of the character (a dot can be replaced by any character)

<*> (asterisk) - match any string of characters

right now I want to check whether a input string like **TTIYYK0AA** includes the string **YYK0** besides the letter **Y** must begin to show in the index 3 in the input string.

That is to say, if the input string is **TTIIYYK0AA** or **TTYYK0AA**, it will return false even though it includes the string YYK0.

Besides the index is not always equal 3, it depends the number of dot.
If the string is **.....YYK0*** , that means the sub-string **YYK0** begins to show in the index of 5 in the input string.

How could I realize that function.

Please help and thank U guys!

Comment: You forgot to post your code

Comment: Provide a sample output at least

Comment: Java: `str.indexOf("YYK0") == 3` --- SQL: `col LIKE '___YYK0%'`

Comment: To check the index : 

    String s = "TTIIYYK0AA";
    if(s.charAt(4)=='Y'){
         //Your code
    }

Comment: What is your exact problem? You want to do that matching in SQL? (if not, why mentioning "column in database table" then?)  Or you want to know how to match a string with regex (the matching way and the string `...YYK0*` is similar to a regex)?  Or you want to know how to retrieve the data from DB? Or you want to write a matching algorithm with your custom syntax?

Comment: ignore the database things...I just wanna know how to match a string with regex

Comment: Clean up your question then.  Avoid unrelated and misleading information, so people can focus on your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***UPDATED:*** Original answer (included at the end) was based on a misinterpretation of the question, a misinterpretation everybody else seems to have made too.

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429272/match-string-in-java/45429382?noredirect=1#comment77820053_45429382):

> It depends on the number of <.> (dot). If the string is `.....YYK0*` **in the database**, it means that the string YYK0 must begin to show in the index of 5 in the input string......

So, you're reading the pattern to match against from the database, and you want to turn that pattern into some function that can be used to test strings in Java.

From your text, it would appear that a `.` can match any *single* character, and that a `*` can match any sequence of characters.

In that case, converting the pattern from the database into a regular expression would likely be the best way to go.

The `.` pattern is the same for regex, i.e. a `.`.
The `*` pattern would be `.*` in regex.
Everything else would need to be escaped (quoted), so it gets matched literally.

You can use this method to convert that pattern into a Java regex:

```
private static Pattern toRegex(String patternFromDb) {
    StringBuffer regex = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\.{1,}|\\*{1,}|[^.*]+").matcher(patternFromDb);
    while (m.find()) {
        String s = m.group();
        switch (s.charAt(0)) {
            case '.':
                // leave dots as they are
                break;
            case '*':
                m.appendReplacement(regex, ".*"); // replace * with .*
                break;
            default:
                m.appendReplacement(regex, Matcher.quoteReplacement(s)); // escape literal match
        }
    }
    return Pattern.compile(m.appendTail(regex).toString());
}
```

You can then use the returned `Pattern` object like this:

```
Pattern p = toRegex("...YYK0*");

if (p.matcher("TTIYYK0AA").matches()) {
    // code here
}
```

---

**Original Answer**

You say "position 4", but your example shows "index 3", so it would appear that your "position" is 1-based.

In Java, you can do the test using:

```java
if (str.indexOf("YYK0") == 3)
```

In SQL, you can do the test using:

```sql
WHERE col LIKE '___YYK0%'
```

Comment: sorry, I must to declare that it's a index 3. And there's another issue : the index is not always 3, some times it will be 4 or others. It depends on the number of <.> (dot). so...,how could I do for that? thank you.

Comment: @xiao Your question says *"letter Y **must** begin to show in the position 4"*. So what is it? It must be at position 4 (aka index 3), or just somewhere after that, or what?

Comment: It depends on the number of <.> (dot). If the string is .....YYK0* in the database, it means that the string YYK0 must begin to show in the index of 5 in the input string......

Comment: @xiao Wow, your question is misleading. Nobody read your question like that.

Comment: I know, I just came out of this thought haha

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, your pattern string is similar to a regex.

Therefore you can do a slight conversion from your pattern to a regex pattern, and simply use String regex matching in Java.

The conversion you need is changing `*` to `.*` (because you want `*` to represent any string)

so the function look like (pseudo-code):

```
boolean match(String string, String pattern) {
    String regexPattern = pattern.replace("\\*", ".*");
    return string.matches(regexPattern);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java we can simply use `string.indexof()` method to get your requirement, 
please find the below code which will be helpful.

```
public class PatternMatch 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String str = "TTIYYK0AA";
       if(str.indexOf("YYK0") == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Success");
            //write what ever your want..
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Fail");
            //write what ever your want
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main( String args[] ) {
      // String to find the pattern.
      String line = "TTIYYK0AA";
      String pattern = "^.{3}YYK0";

      // Creating a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Creating Matcher object
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("MATCHED");
      }else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why put `()` capture group in pattern? Why end with `.*` if you use `find()`?

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, I have edited the code. I forgot to remove .* from the final code and posted the code at practice time... :-)